# TCP Dump received from Verizon, along with an abuse notice

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

Apologies in advance if this Question is not a good fit for your forum, but I hope it is and someone can help. I'm a FIOS customer and received from "abuse@verizon.net" a TCP dump as part of an email stating the below. I am looking for some guidance in how to parse out this log, as I really can't make heads or tails of it, and would hate to have Verizon pull my plug. As requested by VZ, I did the requisite AV/RootKit/Malware scans on all devices, using 3 different applications.

After getting the email below, I asked them for any additional information, and this one line was all that was provided:

The only other information that was reported to us was the following:

"Our logs show that malicious attempts were made from your network against machines in our domain. This is definitely not an authorized request and we view it as an attempt to probe our network for a vulnerability."

Everything in the below pastebin is what I got from Verizon, except I changed my IP address' last 2 to the ".yy.zzz" All the "xx.xx" below came from Verizon.

Any help appreciated, and in advance thanks.

http://pastebin.com/8QS0QFWS

Comment: God, Verizon sucks.

Comment: If I'm reading the cap right, it does look like the system is DOSing a webserver on 80 and 8080.